# Installing MOM 2005 agents on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to get the agent to install on the Windows 7 test box I have here, and it's a no go, says the RPC server is not available. The only thing I found out there from M$ is that MOM2005SP1 isn't supported on Server 2008 R2 or Win7, but is on Server 2008 with a hotfix. Has anyone been able to find a workaround to manage Win7 clients, or should i just consider a move to SCOM 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 are explicitly not supported by MOM 2005 SP1 (as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953140) which was released over 4 years ago on August 1, 2005... I'd say it's about time to start transitioning to SCOM.

Comparison of the features of MOM 2005 and SCOM here: http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/operationsmanager/en/us/compare-products.aspx

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft, although not for the System Center team, nor in a sales role.  Recommendations/opinions are my own. :)

Comment: I've installed SCOM and begun testing, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

MOM2005 console runs on windows 7 client
There is no agent to support windows 2008 servers, only windows 2000 and 2003
It's a good method to Microsoft to say "buy scom2007" 
In this case, you must change your master server, your db and update all clients

My advice, change to Nagios

Comment: Problem is long since solved, and I'll pass on anything non-windows based for monitoring.